# content_main.xml file crashes when ScrollView added in beginning and end

Tags: android, scrollview

I have `ScrollView` in the beginning like this

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp" />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView"
     android:layout_column="1"
     android:background="@mipmap/lpussy"
     android:ContentDescription="@string/desc"
     tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
     android:layout_width="200dp"
     android:layout_height="230dp" />`

 ......Then at the end

<ScrollView>
```

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: xml file shows blank upon refresh

Comment: just add simple scrollview without any other constraint and add any layout like linear/relative/frame layout to the primary child and then add image in it

Comment: by constraint do you mean wrap content?

Comment: remove align parent start/ margin top

Comment: scrollview to match parent and add fillviewport to true

Answer (score 0):

`ScrollView` can host only one direct child.`ViewGoup` such as `LinearLayout`,`RelativeLayout` can act as the direct child of the `ScrollView`.And then,add the other children into the `ViewGoup` .
Here is the demo

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:background="@mipmap/lpussy"
            android:ContentDescription="@string/desc"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="230dp" />`

        ......Then at the end
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: thanks for the advice. not sure how to modify code accordingly. I changed ScrollView to the beginning but file still won't open. Will post my new file

Comment: If you show us the log,we care help you find the problem more effectively.And I edited  the answer ,you may take a look at it.